# Swagger for Asp.Net Mvc Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I am trying to build a microservice web content api which is a simple ASP.NET MVC Web Project.

My Question is, how can I create a main page which is documentation for routes just like swagger for WEB APIs

I have a RouteConfig.cs like below

```
routes.MapRoute(RouteNames.X,
                "X/{action}",
                new { controller = "XController", action = "XAction" });

            routes.MapRoute(RouteNames.Y,
                "Y/{action}",
                new { controller = "YController", action = "YAction" });

            routes.MapRoute(RouteNames.Z,
                "Z/{action}",
                new { controller = "ZController", action = "ZAction" });
```

Comment: Why do not you want to use swagger?

Comment: Use swashbuckle, a generator of swagger and swagger UI documentation for asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First...add the WebApiConfig.cs file in App_Start folder and above code use in **asp.net mvc** not for **asp.net mvc webapi**.  Currently you are mapping the wrong thing.  Below I have the sample code & link.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",                
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

[Getting Started with ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)