# ASP.NET MVC 5 Controllers and Swagger

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, swagger

Is there a way to use Swagger to decorate the ASP.NET MVC 5 controllers?

It does work for Web API controllers. However, we have ASP.NET MVC 5  controllers that return JSON results and we would like to document those endpoints using Swagger and expose the /swagger endpoint to display them.

Comment: Do these links answer your question? [Generating Swagger docs in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58594322/113116), [Swagger for ASP.NET MVC website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44933931/113116), [Swagger/Swashbuckle doc generation only for API controllers within an MVC core app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63802868/113116)

Comment: No, they don't. Some affirm that it is not doable thus was my question. I was hoping for that someone was able to do it.

Comment: Swagger doesn't work with MVC controllers . It only works with ApiController for a Restful APIs.